# Magento 2: Move shipping address popup below address options

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, magento-2.1.7, modal-popup

I am trying to remove modal popup for new shipping address form in checkout and place it below saved address as a div.

Have anyone idea about this?

Comment: Any solution on this?